# Opensearch filter by multiple fields with different values

Tags: filter, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, term-query

The data from opensearch index:

```
{
    "_index" : "demoid",
    "_id" : "50014",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "gender" : "FEMALE",
      "transactionNumber" : "JPP-SD",
      "shortname" : "nameS",
      "firstname" : "BLA BLA FIRST.",
      "result" : "SUCCESS",
      "channel" : "WEB",
      "status" : "COMPLETED",
      "@timestamp" : "2022-12-09T07:01:46.367349646Z",
      "id" : 50014
    }
```

Mappings:
......

```
  "shortname": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
     "status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
```

.....  the ones used in fulltextsearch has the format in template as "shortname" the others like "status".

What i want to achieve is this:

I want to filter all the data by a given list of "status"es, "channel"s and "shortname"s and this result to be applied with a must option for a full text search over some columns.

I have tried using the term and terms into the filter, but for some reason this does not bring any data as a result...

This is the query i want:

```
GET demoid/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "FEMALE"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "channel": [
              "WEB", "Android"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "firstname",
              "shortname",
              "transactionNumber"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "query": "nameS"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "shortname.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However this brings no results:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

But when i write it like this:

```
GET demoid/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "firstname",
              "shortname",
              "transactionNumber"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "query": "nameS"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": "FEMALE"
          }
        }
      ], 
      "should": [
        {
         "match": {
           "channel": "WEB"
         } 
        }, 
        {
          "match": {
            "channel": "OtherChannel"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "shortname.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I receive the data correctly.

Took them one by one and seen that the issue is from filter. Does the filter allows only one "term" in it or does not do the thing that supposed to do?

image: opensearchproject/opensearch:2.3.0
image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:2.3.0

thank you!

PS: I have tried even here: https://playground.opensearch.org/app/dev_tools#/console

this query and no result:

```
GET opensearch_dashboards_sample_data_flights/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "FlightNum": "9HY9SWR"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "DestCountry": [
              "AU"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "DestCountry": {
              "query": "Sydney"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```